# Necesito indicar cuantas veces se repite el mayor valor de un arreglo

Tags: c#

Debo indicarle a la consola que imprima el numero de veces que un valor se repite, en este caso, es el int mayor, que seria el mayor valor del vector, intente unas cuantas cosas, pero estoy atascado, dejare aqui el codigo.

Si puedo hacer que me diga cual es el numero mayor, pero necesito que me diga cuantas veces el numero mayor o el int valor se repite.

Tenia uno que era para cuando se repetian ciertos numeros, e intente editarlo, pero no me funciono.

```
        int[] numero = new int[10];
        int i;
        int mayor = -1;
        int indice = 0;


        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Ejercicio 1");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Leer 10 numeros enteros, almacenarlos en un vector y determinar el mayor");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        for (i = 0; i < numero.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Digite un numero {0}", i);
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numero[i]);

        }

        for (i = 0; i < numero.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + " - " + numero[i]);


        }

        for (i = 0; i < numero.Length; i++)
        {
            if (numero[i] > mayor)
            {
                mayor = numero[i];
                indice = i;
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("El mayor es {0} y su posicion es {1}", mayor, indice);



        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ya tienes el número mayor del vector, ahora solo falta volver a recorrer el vector y comparar cada una de las posiciones del vector (`numero[i]`) con el valor de `mayor` y cuando los valores sean iguales aumentas a uno la variable que tengas como contador.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
int contador = 0;

for (i = 0; i < numero.Length; i++)
{
    if (numero[i] == mayor)
    {
        contador++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("El número mayor del vector es {0} y se repite {1} veces", mayor, contador);
```

Comment: Intente este, en si me parece correcto, pero lo que hace el ejecutarlo es que simplemente me repite el mismo valor que el numero mayor, es decir, si el numero mayor es 80, dira que se repite 80 veces. Lo cual, viendo el codigo que pusiste parece todo bien, no se porque hace eso

Comment: Ups, toda la razon, ya lo arregle.

Comment: Gracias, eso funciono, también me servirá de ejemplo para otros ejercicios que debo hacer, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La forma mas simple de realizarlo es si te ayuda linq, te dejo un ejemplo

```
List<int> numero = new List<int>;

Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Ejercicio 1");
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Leer 10 numeros enteros, almacenarlos en un vector y determinar el mayor");
Console.WriteLine("");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite un numero {0}", i);

    int temp=0;
    if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temp))
    {
        numero.Add(temp);
    }
}

int index =0;
foreach (int item in numero)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", index, item);
    index++;
}

var result = (from item in numero
              group item by item into g
              orderby g.Count() descending
              select new {
                 item = g.Key,
                 count = g.Count()
              }).First();

Console.WriteLine("El mayor es {0} y se repite {1} veces", result.item, result.count);
```

Cuando evaluas repetidos no tienes un unico indice que reportar porque hay varios valores, por eso lo que informas es cual es el item y la cantidad de veces que se repite

Comment: Parece mas una tarea, habría que ver si le está permitido usar Linq, ya que hay veces que en temas como arreglos les piden hacerlo a mano.

Comment: ya se estan planeando las caracteristicas de C# 8, que a esta altura no se permita usar linq, solo es posible en la mentalidad de alguien que atrasa

Comment: no leandro. Cuando se enseña, se empieza por lo basico, porque se enseña a pensar el algoritmo, a pensar como se resuelve. Usar linq esta bien, pero una vez que uno sabe la idea general de que tiene que ser el algoritmo y como se soluciona el problema.

Comment: Mi estimado @LeandroTuttini considera que la persona que pregunta está recién iniciando, sé que tienes buenas intenciones para comentar sobre las bondades épicas de C# y muchos de los que andamos en el sitio lo sabemos. Trata de ajustar la respuesta a un nivel inicial y será un golazo a lo Zlatan. Que la fuerza os acompañe.